# how to go back to previous destination from fragment two to fragment one on button click in Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Jetpack navigation to navigate between the fragments.Since I am using it for the first time I am unaware about how it will navigate from fragment two to fragment one on click of a button or based on some condition in the application.Please let me know if anyone knows about it

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes:

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener(){
   activity?.onNavigateUp()
}
```

or

```
val activity = requireActivity()
yourButton.setOnClickListener(){
 if (activity is YourMainActivity) {
            activity.onSupportNavigateUp()
            //or
            activity.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```